# In protocol design, why would you ever use 2 ports?

Tags: ftp, protocols, network-protocols

When a TCP Server does a socket accept on a port, it gets a new socket to work with that Client.
The accepting socket remains valid for that port and can accept further clients on that port.

Why did the original FTP specification [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) decide to create both a control port and a data port?

**Would there be any reason to do this in a similar custom protocol?**

It seems to me that this could have been easily specified on a single port.

Given all the problems with firewalls and NATS with FTP, it seems that a single port would have been much better.

For a general protocol implementation, the only reason I could think that you would want to do this is so that you can serve the files from a different host than the commands are going to.

Comment: You have to remember that FTP was specified before NAT and Firewalls were the norm.

Comment: The question still remains the same though, why did they chose 2 ports?

Comment: See section 2.3 which has a nice ASCII diagram of the FTP happening with one local host and two remote hosts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The initial rationale behind this was so that you could:

- Continue sending and receiving control instruction on the control connection while you are transfering data.
- Have more than one data connection active at the same time.
- The server decides when it's ready to send you data.

True, they could have achieved the same result by specifying a complicated multiplexing protocol integrated to the FTP protocol, but since at that time NAT was a non issue, they chose to use what already existed, TCP ports.

Here is an example:

Alice wants two files from Bob. Alice connects to Bob port 21 and asks for the files. Bob open connections to Alice port 20 when it's ready and send the files there. Meanwhile, Charles needs a file on Alice's server. Charles connects to 21 on Alice and asks for the file. Alice connects to port 20 on Charles when ready, and sends the files.

As you can see, port 21 is for client connecting to servers and port 20 is for servers connecting to clients, but those clients could still serve files on 21.

Both ports serve a totally different purpose, and again for sake of simplicity, they chose to use two different ports instead of implementing a negotiation protocol.

Comment: Re 1) But you could just create another socket on the same port as the control connection.  I'm not against creating 2 connections, just against 2 ports.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your issue.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the control protocol is human readable as many things were in that era, specifically so that a person could use the protocol manually while data is transfering on another port. See the answer from @IfLoop below.

Comment: The ports here seem to be misleading. Both 20 and 21 are server ports. For example if server Bob needs to transfer two files to client Alice, Bob opens his own port 20 and connects to high port of Alice for transmission.

Comment: Both 20 and 21 are server ports only if Passive mode is being used. If active mode are being used then port 20 is on the client side i.e. the server connects back to the client. The above answer describes Active mode which was the original and is now considered insecure.

Answer (score 9):

Because FTP allows for separate control and data. IIRC, as originally designed, you could have 3 hosts: Host A could ask host B to send data to host C.

Comment: Yes, and this is a feature I sorely miss in modern FTP clients (since the protocol still allows you to do it) -- when connected over some spotty wifi it would be nice to be able to transfer large files directly from one backbone-connected server to another without touching the data on loopback.

Comment: Oh yeah - I forgot about a client controlling a transfer between 2 remote hosts...

Answer (score 8):

FTP was designed at a time when the stupidity of a modern firewall was inconceivable. TCP ports are intended for this functionality; multiplexing multiple connections on a single IP. They are *NOT* a substitute for Access Control Lists. They are *NOT* intended to extend IPv4 to 48 bits addresses, either.

Any new non-IPv6 protocol will have to deal with the current mess, so it should stick to a small contiguous range of ports.

Answer (score 6):

FTP has a very long history, being one of the first ARPANET protocols back in the early seventies (for instance, see [RFC114 from 1971](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc114.html)). Design decisions which may seem odd now made more sense then. Connections were much slower, and performing the connection control "out of band" probably seemed a good move with the available network technology.

The current [RFC959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) includes a good section on history, linking to earlier RFCs, if you fancy doing a little archaeology...

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, the issue wasn't that FTP uses two (i.e., more than one) ports. The issue is that the control connection is initiated by the client and the data channel was initiated by the server. The largest difference between FTP and HTTP is that in HTTP the client pulls data and in FTP the server pushes it. The NAT issue is related to the server pushing data through a firewall that doesn't know to expect the connection.

FTP's usage of separate ports for control and data is rather elegant IMHO. Think about all of the headaches in HTTP surrounding the multiplexing of control and data - think Trailing headers, rules surrounding pipelined requests, connection keep-alives, and what not. Much of that is avoided by explicitly separating control and data not to mention it is possible to do interesting things like encrypt one and not the other or make the control channel have a higher QoS than the data.

Answer (score 4):

Like many of the older wire protocols, FTP is suited for use by humans.  That is it is quite easy to use FTP from a terminal session.  The designers of FTP anticipated that users might want to continue working with the remote host while data was transferring.  This would have been difficult if command and data were going over the same channel.

Answer (score 4):

The IETF has banned the practice of allocating more than one port for new protocols so we likely won't be seeing this in the future.

Newer IP protocols such as SCTP are designed to solve some of the shortcommings of TCP that could lead one to use multiple ports.  TCPs 'head-of-line' blocking prevents you from having multiple separate requests/streams in flight which can be a problem for some realtime applications.

Comment: I find your first sentence very interesting. Do you have any further reading material on the topic that talks about the reasons for that?

Comment: @bamboon I'm pretty sure that the reason is the scarcity of port numbers. There are only 49,152 assignable ports for TCP and UDP (49,152 - 65,535 are reserved for the dynamic allocation pool.) 49,000 port numbers seemed like a lot back in the 70s, but not so much anymore.

Answer (score 2):

FTP is an old protocol.  That's really the only reason.  The designers thought that the amount of data flowing over the data port would make it so that they couldn't send control commands in a timely manner, so they did it as two ports.  Firewalls, and especially NAT, came much later.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the RTSP + RTP protcol. It is a similar design : each stream can be sent on a different port, and statistics about jitter, reordering etc... is sent on yet another port.

Plus there is no connection since it is UDP. However it was developped when firewall where already something banal (sorry for my english), so a mode was developped where all this connection could be embedded in one TCP connection with HTTP syntax.

Guess what ? The multi port protocol is much simpler (IMO) to implement than the http multiplexed one and and it has a lot more features. If you are not concerned with firewall problem, why choose complicated multiplexing scheme when there is already one existing (TCP port)?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of FTP its not just only a different port but could also be a different host and its probably because of this in the [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959):

```
In another situation a user might wish to transfer files between

two hosts, neither of which is a local host. The user sets up

control connections to the two servers and then arranges for a

data connection between them. In this manner, control information

is passed to the user-PI but data is transferred between the

server data transfer processes. Following is a model of this

server-server interaction.

                    Control     ------------   Control 
                    ---------->| User-FTP |<----------- 
                    |          | User-PI  |           | 
                    |          |   "C"    |           | 
                    V          ------------           V 
            --------------                        -------------- 
            | Server-FTP |   Data Connection      | Server-FTP | 
            |    "A"     |<---------------------->|    "B"     | 
            -------------- Port (A)      Port (B) -------------- 
 
 
                                 Figure 2 
The protocol requires that the control connections be open while

data transfer is in progress. It is the responsibility of the

user to request the closing of the control connections when

finished using the FTP service, while it is the server who takes

the action. The server may abort data transfer if the control

connections are closed without command.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think they did this so that while a transfer was occuring you could continue to work with the server and start new transfers easily (if your client could support this).

Note that passive mode solves nearly all firewall/NAT problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it's just a bad design choice in the first place. In the old ages where it was invented, firewall and NAT were not existing ... Nowadays, the real question is more "why people still want to use FTP" ? Everything FTP does can be done using HTTP in a better way.

Comment: except a DIR method.  HTTP has excluded that, though most servers optionally provide it in a non-standard way.

Comment: @tokenmacguy: true, but can be accomplished using webdav

Comment: @grieve: HTTP is much easier to secure

Comment: @MatthieuP Not really. They're both pretty trivial to secure with TLS. Neither HTTP nor FTP was designed with security in mind. Same goes for TCP and IPv4, for that matter. Security was an afterthought in all of the above protocols and is generally accomplished via entirely separate protocols, such as TLS and IPsec.

Answer (score 0):

[image: see this image]

When a user starts a FTP session with a remote host, FTP first sets up a control TCP connection on server port number 21. The client side of FTP sends the user identification and password over this control connection. The client side of FTP also sends, over the control connection, commands to change the remote directory.

When the user requests a file transfer (either to, or from, the remote host), FTP opens a TCP data connection on server port number 20. FTP sends exactly one file over the data connection and then closes the data connection. If, during the same session, the user wants to transfer another file, FTP opens another data TCP connection. Thus, with FTP, the control connection remains open throughout the duration of the user session, but a new data connection is created for each file transferred within a session (i.e., the data connections are non-persistent).